# PHP join two table where two column in one table contains from_ID and to_ID refer to id in another table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, inner-join

I have two table

**fnf**

```
id
from_ID
to_ID
```

**users**

```
id
name
```

When, I send friend request, my id from users table goes to from_ID. And When someone else send friend request, his id goes to from_ID and my id goes to to_ID.

I got my all friend id's from **fnf** table like bellow

```
$getmyfriends=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM fnf WHERE (from_ID='$logged' || to_ID ='$logged')");    
$getmyfriendsnum=mysqli_num_rows($getmyfriends);
if($getmyfriendsnum !=0){
while($getmyfriendsrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getmyfriends)){
    $from_ID=$getmyfriendsrow['from_ID'];
    $to_ID=$getmyfriendsrow['to_ID'];
        if($from_ID==$logged){
            $myf=$to_ID;
        }else if($to_ID==$logged){
            $myf=$from_ID;
        }
   }
}
```

Now, I am trying to get my non-friends id's from table **users**

```
$getalluser=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`!='$myf' ");
$getallusernum=mysqli_num_rows($getalluser);
if($getallusernum !=0){
while($getalluserrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getalluser)){
    $nonfriendid=$getalluserrow['id'];
    echo $nonfriendid."</br>";
    }
}
```

I am not getting actuals non-friends id's. even I tried putting 2nd query into first while loop, that is also bad, Actually, I don't understant INNER JOIN also.

Who to get non-friends id's....into 2nd while loop.

Comment: @NotoriousPet0, Ofcourse Bro, I did it. and Thank you so much for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
`id` 
from 
`users` 
where 
`id` 
not in 
    (select 
     `from_ID` 
     from 
     `fnf`) 
and 
`id` 
not in 
    (select 
     `to_ID` 
     from 
     `fnf`)
```